How to define an icon like FA icons in my webpage?
As Codeberg icon is not in FA, I try to include in my webpage (links simplified) as follows:
<script src='js/faCodeberg.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css">
...
<i class="fa-brands fa-codeberg"></i>

where js/faCodeberg.js is
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
var prefix = 'fab';
var iconName = 'codeberg';
var width = 512;
var height = 512;
var aliases = [];
var unicode = 'f366';
var svgPathData = 'M0.00 8.56C0.00 14.69 4.25 14.69 4.25 14.69 4.25 14.69 10.92 6.07 10.92 6.07 10.87 5.84 10.65 6.07 10.65 6.07 10.65 6.07 17.04 6.07 17.04 6.07 17.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 14.84 6.07 14.84 6.07 14.84 6.07 12.76 6.07 12.76 6.07 12.76 6.07 11.42 6.07 11.42 6.07 11.42 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.65 6.07 8.65 6.07 8.65 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 4.89 6.07 4.89 6.07 4.89 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.82 6.07 9.82 6.07 9.82 6.07 12.89 6.07 12.89 6.07 12.89 6.07 13.94 6.07 13.94 6.07 13.94 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.08 6.07 10.08 6.07 10.08 6.07 6.54 6.07 6.54 6.07 6.54 6.07 5.61 6.07 5.61 6.07 5.61 6.07 9.92 6.07 9.92 6.07 9.92 6.07 10.48 6.07 10.48 6.07 10.48 6.07 14.50 6.07 14.50 6.07 14.50 6.07 15.36 6.07 15.36 6.07 15.36 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.73 6.07 10.73 6.07 10.73 6.07 14.78 6.07 14.78 6.07 15.58 3.57 10.81 1.81 14.78 1.65 11.20 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 0.00 4.14 0.00 8.56ZM10.44 13.30C10.44 13.30 10.99 13.30 10.99 13.30 10.99 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.88 12.86 14.88 12.86 14.88 12.86 10.44 13.30 10.44 13.30ZM13.71 12.86C13.71 12.86 13.15 12.86 13.15 12.86 13.15 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.30 12.43 10.30 12.43 10.30 12.43 13.71 12.86 13.71 12.86ZM9.13 12.43C9.13 12.43 8.58 12.43 8.58 12.43 8.58 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.08 12.00 7.08 12.00 7.08 12.00 9.13 12.43 9.13 12.43Z';

exports.definition = {
  prefix: prefix,
  iconName: iconName,
  icon: [
    width,
    height,
    aliases,
    unicode,
    svgPathData
  ]};

exports.faCodeberg = exports.definition;
exports.prefix = prefix;
exports.iconName = iconName;
exports.width = width;
exports.height = height;
exports.ligatures = aliases;
exports.unicode = unicode;
exports.svgPathData = svgPathData;
exports.aliases = aliases;

and css/site.css contains
.fa-codeberg:before {
  content: "\f366"; }

by imitation of CSS and JS for icons in Font Awesome GitHub. However, it is not working, as another symbol appears instead of the icon. What am I doing wrong or what I lack to do?
Thanks!

Have you checked the ‘official’ way to include your own icon? But this won’t work if that code is already taken.

A workaround would be with just CSS, to include the SVG in data:image/svg+xml...:


.fa-codeberg:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M0.00 8.56C0.00 14.69 4.25 14.69 4.25 14.69 4.25 14.69 10.92 6.07 10.92 6.07 10.87 5.84 10.65 6.07 10.65 6.07 10.65 6.07 17.04 6.07 17.04 6.07 17.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 15.04 6.07 14.84 6.07 14.84 6.07 14.84 6.07 12.76 6.07 12.76 6.07 12.76 6.07 11.42 6.07 11.42 6.07 11.42 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.97 6.07 8.65 6.07 8.65 6.07 8.65 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 6.07 4.89 6.07 4.89 6.07 4.89 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.41 6.07 9.82 6.07 9.82 6.07 9.82 6.07 12.89 6.07 12.89 6.07 12.89 6.07 13.94 6.07 13.94 6.07 13.94 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.59 6.07 10.08 6.07 10.08 6.07 10.08 6.07 6.54 6.07 6.54 6.07 6.54 6.07 5.61 6.07 5.61 6.07 5.61 6.07 9.92 6.07 9.92 6.07 9.92 6.07 10.48 6.07 10.48 6.07 10.48 6.07 14.50 6.07 14.50 6.07 14.50 6.07 15.36 6.07 15.36 6.07 15.36 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.18 6.07 10.73 6.07 10.73 6.07 10.73 6.07 14.78 6.07 14.78 6.07 15.58 3.57 10.81 1.81 14.78 1.65 11.20 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 6.78 -6.35 0.00 4.14 0.00 8.56ZM10.44 13.30C10.44 13.30 10.99 13.30 10.99 13.30 10.99 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.54 13.30 14.88 12.86 14.88 12.86 14.88 12.86 10.44 13.30 10.44 13.30ZM13.71 12.86C13.71 12.86 13.15 12.86 13.15 12.86 13.15 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.78 12.86 10.30 12.43 10.30 12.43 10.30 12.43 13.71 12.86 13.71 12.86ZM9.13 12.43C9.13 12.43 8.58 12.43 8.58 12.43 8.58 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.78 12.43 7.08 12.00 7.08 12.00 7.08 12.00 9.13 12.43 9.13 12.43Z"></path></svg>');
}
<i class="fa-brands fa-codeberg"></i>



But I think you'd like to have this with the proper looks, the svgPathData provided by you is not looking good...


.fa-codeberg:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 4.233 4.233"><defs><linearGradient xlink:href="%23a" id="b" x1="42519.285" x2="42575.336" y1="-7078.789" y2="-6966.931" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"/><linearGradient id="a"><stop offset="0" stop-color="%23000" stop-opacity="0"/><stop offset=".495" stop-color="%23000" stop-opacity=".3"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="%23000" stop-opacity=".3"/></linearGradient></defs><path fill="url(%23b)" d="M42519.285-7078.79a.76.568 0 0 0-.738.675l33.586 125.888a87.182 87.182 0 0 0 39.381-33.763l-71.565-92.52a.76.568 0 0 0-.664-.28z" paint-order="stroke markers fill" style="font-variation-settings:normal" transform="translate(-1030.156 172.97) scale(.02428)"/><path fill="%23000" d="M2.113.12A2.117 2.117 0 0 0 .32 3.36l1.764-2.28c.013-.017.045-.017.058 0l1.764 2.28A2.117 2.117 0 0 0 2.113.12z" paint-order="markers fill stroke"/></svg>');
}
<i class="fa-brands fa-codeberg"></i>



The code I found that is close-to-mine, on the upper-right corner of https://librewolf.net/, with the CSS separately (suggested by Mark Schultheiss):


.my-icon {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
}
<svg class="my-icon" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 4.233 4.233" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor"><path opacity="0.5" d="M42519.285-7078.79a.76.568 0 0 0-.738.675l33.586 125.888a87.182 87.182 0 0 0 39.381-33.763l-71.565-92.52a.76.568 0 0 0-.664-.28z" transform="matrix(.02428 0 0 .02428 -1030.156 172.97)"></path><path d="M11249.461-1883.696c-12.74 0-23.067 10.327-23.067 23.067 0 4.333 1.22 8.58 3.522 12.251l19.232-24.863c.138-.18.486-.18.624 0l19.233 24.864a23.068 23.068 0 0 0 3.523-12.252c0-12.74-10.327-23.067-23.067-23.067z" transform="translate(-1030.156 172.97) scale(.09176)"></path></svg>




Instead of the style attribute you could also use css with a class for example .my-icon {   width: 4em;   height: 4em; }

@MarkSchultheiss Thank you, I updated my answer.
